# Summary stats by factor level for multiple variables

Tags: r, summary

I want to produce dataframes containing summary statistics for each factor level for multiple variables.

For example if I have the following dataframe

```
Factor <- c("A","A","A","B","B","B")
Variable1 <- c(3,4,5,4,5,3)
Variable2 <- c(7,9,14,16,10,10)
mydf <- data.frame(Factor, Variable1, Variable2)
mydf
  Factor Variable1 Variable2
1      A         3         7
2      A         4         9
3      A         5        14
4      B         4        16
5      B         5        10
6      B         3        10
```

and I have the following function that I want to use to produce my summary stats:

```
my.summary <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){result <- c(n=as.integer(length(x)),
Mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(x, na.rm=TRUE), SeM = SEM(x),
Median=median(x),   Min=min(x), Max=max(x))}
```

To apply this to factor levels of Variable1 I can do this:

```
ddply(mydf, c("Factor"), function(x) my.summary(x$Variable1))
  Factor n Mean SD       SeM Median Min Max
1      A 3    4  1 0.5773503      4   3   5
2      B 3    4  1 0.5773503      4   3   5
```

Now I can do the same for Variable 2:

```
ddply(mydf, c("Factor"), function(x) my.summary(x$Variable2))
```

Which is easy enough if I just have 2 variables. However, if I had lots of variables this would be a pain. So how can I solve this so that I can produce a dataframe of the summary stats for each variable/factor level without having to adjust the code?

I have tried using aggregate.data.frame but it doesn't work using my.summary. It works using summary but produces one big data frame.

Thanks

Comment: `melt` your data into long format so you have `variable` column and a `value` column, then use both `"Factor"` and `"variable"` as grouping variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could melt your data first:

```
library(reshape2)

df <- melt(mydf,id.vars = 1)
df1 <- ddply(df, c("Factor","variable"), function(x) my.summary(x$value))
```

If you want to split the data by the different variables you can use `split()`:

```
df2 <- split(df1,df1$variable)
```

And if you want those split dataframes in the global environment, you can use `list2env()` which will make two new dataframes, `Variable1` and `Variable2` (or more if you have more variables):

```
list2env(df2,.GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: thanks for that. It works nicely. But what if I want a separate dataframe for each variable?

Comment: I've updated to show how you can split the results into a list of dataframes, which can then be sent to the global environment.

Comment: Great, just been trawling google to find out how to do that to no avail!

Answer (score 3):

You could use summarise_each from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

mydf %>% group_by(Factor) %>%
         summarise_each(funs(my.summary(.)))
```

After modifying your function to return a list:

```
my.summary <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){result <- list(c(n=as.integer(length(x)),
                                                  Mean=mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), SD=sd(x, na.rm=TRUE),
                                                  Median=median(x),   Min=min(x), Max=max(x)))}
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
 setDT(mydf)[, unlist(lapply(.SD, my.summary),recursive=FALSE), Factor]
 my.summary <- function(x, na.rm=TRUE){list(n= length(x),
                                  Mean=mean(x),
                                  SD=sd(x),
                                  Median=median(x), 
                                  Min=min(x),
                                  Max=max(x))}
```